# What do the words 「ばかこくでねえ」 and 「へえるはずさ」 mean?

Tags: words, manga

I have found it in a manga. It is a dialogue discussing to the third person going into a Pachinko shop.

Here is the full sentence.

> **ばかこくでねえ へえるはずさ** あとで パチンコ屋【や】の店【てん】員【いん】がしらべたらよ。

What do the words ばかこくでねえ and へえるはずさ mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ばかこくでねえ is a dialectal way of saying ばかこくんじゃない, ばかをいうな　'Don't be silly.'   ばか(を)こく means [馬鹿]{ばか}(なこと)を言う, 'say a stupid thing' 'be stupid'.

へえる is a dialectal or collapsed way of saying [入]{はい}る. へえるはずさ, 入るはずさ literally means 'should go in', so probably 'He should go in' 'I'm sure he will go into the Pachiko shop'.